# How to fix ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject error?

Tags: java, gradle, annotation-processing

I am getting following error when I deploy my application:

```
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:49)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:108)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:58)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:65)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/configurationprocessor/json/JSONObject
    at com.rossmoor.jenarktomds.services.web.GrfPortalClientServiceImpl.getAccessToken(GrfPortalClientServiceImpl.java:53)
    at com.rossmoor.jenarktomds.services.web.GrfPortalClientServiceImpl.downloadAllGrfUsers(GrfPortalClientServiceImpl.java:325)
    at com.rossmoor.jenarktomds.services.DataProcessorImpl.testGrfApi(DataProcessorImpl.java:1939)
    at com.rossmoor.jenarktomds.services.DataProcessorImpl$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$716e474b.invoke(<generated>)
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:793)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:763)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:708)
    at com.rossmoor.jenarktomds.services.DataProcessorImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$21e20f26.testGrfApi(<generated>)
    at com.rossmoor.jenarktomds.JenarkToMdsApplication.run(JenarkToMdsApplication.java:76)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:771)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:755)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1306)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1295)
    at com.rossmoor.jenarktomds.JenarkToMdsApplication.main(JenarkToMdsApplication.java:59)
    ... 8 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject
    at java.base/java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:445)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:587)
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.LaunchedURLClassLoader.loadClass(LaunchedURLClassLoader.java:151)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:520)
    ... 30 more
```

The code that causes the error looks like this:

```
   // create request body
    JSONObject request = new JSONObject();
    request.put("username", configurationProperties.getGrfPortalUserName());
    request.put("password", configurationProperties.getGrfPortalUserPwd());

    // set headers
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.add("API-Key", "{{apiKey}}");
    headers.add("Authorization", "Basic {{authorization}}");

    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<>(request.toString(), headers);

    if (Logger.isInfoEnabled()) Logger.info("Sending request to GRF Portal");
    // send request and parse result
    ResponseEntity<String> loginResponse = restTemplate
            .exchange(GRF_LOGIN_URL, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
    if (loginResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK)
    {
        JSONObject userJson = new JSONObject(loginResponse.getBody());

        if (Logger.isInfoEnabled()) Logger.info("Token Data = " + userJson);

        this.AccessToken = String.valueOf(userJson.get("token"));

        System.out.println("AccessToken = " + AccessToken);
    }
    else if (loginResponse.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED)
    {
        // nono... bad credentials
        if (Logger.isErrorEnabled()) Logger.error("nono... bad credentials");
    }
```

Please note the error occurs only in deployment on production server. I take following steps to deploy:

1. Build the app using Gradle build command.
2. Convert Jar file to exe using [Jar2exe](https://www.jar2exe.com/)
3. Deploy the exe file as a windows service (Using an installer program).

When I run the program on development or production server using IntelliJ idea the error does not occur. What could be problem here?

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.0'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.rossmoor'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '17'

configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-oauth2-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest'
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    developmentOnly 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-devtools'
    runtimeOnly 'com.microsoft.sqlserver:mssql-jdbc'
    annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.security:spring-security-test'
    annotationProcessor "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor"

//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.orm/hibernate-core
//    implementation group: 'org.hibernate.orm', name: 'hibernate-core', version: '6.0.2.Final'
//
//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.transaction/jakarta.transaction-api
//    implementation group: 'jakarta.transaction', name: 'jakarta.transaction-api', version: '2.0.1'
//
//    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/jakarta.persistence/jakarta.persistence-api
//    implementation group: 'jakarta.persistence', name: 'jakarta.persistence-api', version: '3.1.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-lang3
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.12.0'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-validator/commons-validator
    implementation group: 'commons-validator', name: 'commons-validator', version: '1.7'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mapstruct/mapstruct
    implementation group: 'org.mapstruct', name: 'mapstruct', version: '1.5.2.Final'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.code.gson/gson
    implementation group: 'com.google.code.gson', name: 'gson', version: '2.9.1'

    implementation files('lib/connection-manager-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/Utils-2.0.0.1.jar')
    implementation files('lib/TinyLog-2.0.0.1.jar')
}

tasks.named('test') {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: I doubt this is a Spring Boot problem as your tags suggest. More likely the Jar2exe step. Is it really `org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject`?

Comment: Yes it is. This is on top: import org.springframework.boot.configurationprocessor.json.JSONObject;

Comment: Which version of Spring do you use? How does your build.gradle file looks like?

Comment: This means that some classes/jars are not included in your exe file. You probably get  the non complete jar (fatJar) or jar2exe removes some when building.

Comment: @Nemanja Added build.gradle details

Comment: @grekier It is a fat jar with 43 MB file. Plain jar size is few kb. Exe size is 43 MB

Comment: exe should be bigger since I guess it should include JVM as well. I don't know jar2exe so I can't be sure... Have you eventually looked at building the app natively to avoid it?

Comment: @grekier jar2exe does not package JRE. It provides parameters which allows us to use a JVM in a folder or default java installation.

Comment: Why does `compileOnly` extend from `annotationProcessor`? Aren’t both predefined and should not be tampered with?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This comes from your build.gradle:

```
annotationProcessor 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
```

Since you have declared as `compileOnly` here:

```
configurations {
    compileOnly {
        extendsFrom annotationProcessor
    }
}
```

but apparently the JSONException is used at run time, it makes your app fail when packaging with Jar2exe. The solution to this could be to include the whole dependency like so:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-configuration-processor'
```

Comment: It’s `JSONObject` in the OP’s stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

Had a lot problems with this too.
Switching to following solved my problems:
*org.json.JSONException

org.json.JSONObject*